# If variable target = fila 1, how do i ask a condition that reports true if target is any of filas

Tags: netlogo

I need a condition where one turtle evaluates if other turtle has variable target any of filas

i have tried, target = filas, target = any? filas, member? target filas (this one works but in my code sometimes target = nobody and creates a netlogo error message)

`set people-ahead min-one-of (other people in-cone (velocidad + espacio-personal + 0.5 )  106.36 with [puesto? = false and  target != any? filas]) [distance myself]`

condition that reports true if target is any of filas

Comment: What is filas? For example, is it a global variable that holds a turtle-set?

Comment: filas is a breed

Answer (score 0):

`breed` is an attribute of a turtle in exactly the same way as other built in variables (such as `size`) or variables defined by a `turtles-own` statement. This means you can directly check with `[breed] of`.

Here is a complete example that checks the `breed` of a selected turtle named target and changes its colour.

```
breed [type1s type1]
breed [type2s type2]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-type1s 20
  [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set color red
  ]
  create-type2s 20
  [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set color yellow
  ]
  ask one-of turtles
  [ set size 2
    let target min-one-of other turtles [distance myself]
    if [breed] of target = type1s [ask target [set color white]]
    if [breed] of target = type2s [ask target [set color blue]]
  ]
end
```

You can also just use the name of the breed to get the turtle-set that contains all the turtles of that breed. I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but I think you probably want to replace:

```
set people-ahead min-one-of (other people in-cone (velocidad + espacio-personal + 0.5 )  106.36 with [puesto? = false and  target != any? filas]) [distance myself]
```

with

```
let candidates (filas in-cone (velocidad + espacio-personal + 0.5) 106.36 with [not puesto?])
set people-ahead min-one-of candidates [distance myself]
```